# MvxFragment ViewModels

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm trying to get Fragments to work when using MvvmCross 3.5.

I have the following fragment:

```
public class MainView
  : MvxFragment<MenuView>
{

public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    this.EnsureBindingContextIsSet(savedInstanceState);
    var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MainView, null);

    return view;
 }
}
```

I have been using the following code for manually initializing the ViewModel:

```
var loaderService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
ViewModel = (T)loaderService.LoadViewModel(
           new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(T), null, null, null), null);
```

This works fine except when the Fragment is resumed at which point the app blows up with a `NullReferenceException`.

I am now trying to use the `MvxCachingFragmentActivity` to handle the lifecycle of the fragments but cannot find any documentation on it.

I have registered the fragments:

```
RegisterFragment<MainView, MainViewModel>(typeof(MainView).Name, bundle);
```

and then shown one:

```
ShowFragment(typeof(MainView).Name, Resource.Id.content_frame, bundle);
```

The fragment loads but ViewModel is null.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: A new example that handles this is available here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Comment: @Martijn00 The link does not exist :(

Answer (score 1):

```
[MvxOwnedViewModelFragment]
```

on the fragment is needed as of 3.5.1